# why is the vertical component of the phasor an imaginary number?

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity, electrical-resistance

I was learning about the phasor representation of AC circuits, and on adding two out of phase phasors they were each resolved in to a horizontal and vertical component to facilitate the addition. What I didn't get was why the vertical component was an imaginary number.

Comment: Perhaps I don't quite get your question but a phasor *is* a complex number, i.e., a phasor has a real part and an imaginary part.  Typically, the [complex plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_plane) is plotted with the real part along the horizontal axis and the imaginary part along the vertical axis.

Answer (score 1):

A phasor is a complex number, first and foremost. We treat it (and name it) like a vector because complex numbers are so conveniently similar to 2D vectors. It is sometimes easier to think of a complex number $z=x+iy$ as a tuple of numbers, $z=(x,y)$, which you might recognize behaves exactly like the vector $(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2$ *under addition*. (Multiplication, of course, is markedly different between complex scalar and real vector spaces.)

This is great, because we can now describe the voltages of our circuit using a geometric picture, and we can manipulate them appropriately with simple vector addition and subtraction. But it is important to remember that we are still dealing with complex numbers, because when we reconcile our phasor solutions with our circuit equations, we should retain properties of the circuit (e.g. phase differences over the time evolution). Indeed, it was only *because* we wrote our equations in complex form $($e.g. $V_S (t) = V_0 e^{i\omega t})$ that we could perform the circuit analysis using phasors. (As for why, well it's simply because complex exponentials are much more user-friendly than a mess of sines and cosines.)